# Mongoid nesting with embeds_many two times of one class

Tags: ruby, json, mongoid

Recently I came across issue I cannot resolve (or google it properly). First, here are the files:

```
#Counter.rb
class Counter
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :pointing, as: :goodvs, store_as: "goodvs"
  embeds_many :pointing, as: :badvs, store_as: "badvs"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pointing

  field :name, type: String
  field :champId, type: Integer
end

#Pointing.rb
class Pointing
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :counter
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :counter

  field :name, type: String
  field :votes, type: Integer
  field :lane, type: String
end
```

## Description

I want to nest Pointing class in Counter class double to make structure like this:

```
{
 name: 'sth',
 champId: 1,
 goodvs: [{
           name: 'sthsth'
           votes: 1
           lane: 'top'
         },
         {
           name: 'sthsth2'
           votes: 4
           lane: 'bot'
         }],
 badvs: [{
           name: 'sthsth'
           votes: 1
           lane: 'mid'
         }]
}
```

Anyone have any solution how to do this? I can make normal structure for nested attributes used once only but I have no clue how to do this properly for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only just started messing around with mongo/mongoid myself but it looks like your class  definition is a bit awry. The details are referenced from the [Mongoid Relations docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html)

Use the `embedded_in` relationship for `embeds_many`. `belongs_to` goes with `has_many`.

```
class Pointing
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :counter

  field :name,   type: String
  field :votes,  type: Integer
  field :lane,   type: String
end
```

If that doesn't fix it... I setup custom relation names slightly differently by using `class_name` to point back to the actual class. The `as:` option is documented to be used when the the child document can belong to many parents but I've not used it enough to say if this is an actual difference or just style.

```
class Counter
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :goodvs, class_name: "Pointing"
  embeds_many :badvs,  class_name: "Pointing"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :goodvs, :badvs

  field :name,    type: String
  field :champId, type: Integer
end
```

Then retrieving the objects I've created with:

```
Counter.each do |c|
  log 'counter name', c.name, c.id
  log 'goodv', c.goodvs
  log 'goodv first', c.goodvs.first.name, c.goodvs.first.id
  log 'badvs', c.badvs
  log 'badvs first', c.badvs.first.name, c.badvs.first.id
end
```

Results in:

```
counter name [sth] [53cfcee66fcb2d2db5000001]
goodv [#<Pointing:0x00000601a395b0>] [#<Pointing:0x00000601a393f8>]
goodv first [mee] [53cfcee66fcb2d2db5000002]
badvs [#<Pointing:0x00000601a37468>] [#<Pointing:0x00000601a372b0>]
badvs first [mee] [53cfcee66fcb2d2db5000002]
```

So different `Pointing` object references but both `goodvs` and `badvs` contain the same mongo document underneath.

Comment: It was my mistake about first point of your answer (other classes got it correctly...) but it didn't fixed it. Second one on the other hand works great! Thank you very much for help. Could you point me to location in doc where I can find info about `class_name` ?

Comment: No worries... Search for "Custom Relation Names" in the relations doc linked at the top of the answer.